# For Loop With Object Table?

Tags: sql, oracle

Say an object with some functions etc. defined on it and I have a table like

`CREATE TABLE person_obj_table OF person_typ;`

Now I want to use a for loop to iterate through the table like so

```
  for x in (select value(t) from person_obj_table t where lastName = 'Smith') loop
    dbms_output.put_line(x.get_fullName);
  end loop;
```

This seems to fail though as x is not recognized as a person_typ. Any clue about what to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the `value(x)` expression a name `v`, and then use that name:

```
for x in (select value(t) v from person_obj_table t where lastName = 'Smith') loop
  dbms_output.put_line(x.v.get_fullName);
end loop;
```